# using external library classes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i have crated a custom library file for the login validation. if i call the custom library at before $this->load->library('form_validation');

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {
     function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper('url'); 
       $this->load->model('loginuser');
       $this->load->library('validate_login','','session_validation');// where validate_login is the custom library class inside applications/libraries/validate_login.php
     }
     function index()
     {
       //my code
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
     }

    }
```

This is the error i got $this->load->library('form_validation'); it works perfectley.
i just want to know Why this code works? Am i overwriting the default libraries?

> Message: Undefined property: VerifyLogin::$form_validation

if i load the library after

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {
     function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper('url'); 
       $this->load->model('loginuser');
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->load->library('validate_login','','session_validation');// where validate_login is the custom library class inside applications/libraries/validate_login.php
     }
     function index()
     {
       //my code
     }

    }
```

Comment: Post your `Validate_login`.

Comment: @Sobiaholic i have added the validate_login in answers..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're loading your libraries wrong. Try one of these;

**Multiple**

```
$this->load->library(array('library1', 'library2'));
```

**Single**

```
$this->load->library('library1');
$this->load->library('library2');
```

Comment: i have used the Single Method, but the second library is not loaded!!

Answer (score 0):

@sobiaholic

this is validate_login

```
class Validate_login extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('loginuser');
     $this->load->helper('url'); 
   }
   function is_logged()
   {
       if(isset($this->session->userdata['my_session_id']))
       {
           if(strlen($this->session->userdata['my_session_id']))
           {
               return TRUE;
           }
           else
           {
               return FALSE;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           return FALSE;
       }
   }
   function validate_login()
   {
      $session_id=$this->session->userdata['my_session_id'];
      $this->db->select('last_activity,user_data');
      $this -> db -> from('sessions');
      $this->db->where('session_id',$session_id);
      $this -> db -> limit(1);
      $query = $this -> db -> get();
      if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
      {
        $results=$query->result();
        $active_session=$this->session_alive($results[0]->last_activity,$session_id);
        if($active_session==TRUE)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->verifylogin->logout();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
   }
   function session_alive($valid_till,$session_id)
   {
       $time_limit=$this->config->item('sess_expiration');
       if (time() - $valid_till > $time_limit) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            if($this->update_session($session_id)==TRUE)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
   }
   function update_session($session_id)
   {
       $new_time=time();
       $data=array('last_activity'=>$new_time);
       $this->db->where('session_id',$session_id);
       $this->db->update('sessions',$data);
       if($this->db->affected_rows())
       {
           return TRUE;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this a library? Or a Controller?

Comment: @Craig this a external library file inside "application/libraries/"

Comment: There's no need to extend the controller class.

Comment: @Craig are you telling me to remove "extends CI_Controller" from "Validate_login extends CI_Controller" ??

Comment: That's right. If it's a Library, then there's no need to extend the controller. The library can be a class on its own.

Comment: @Craig  then how "$this->load()" will work without the Parent class "CI_Controller"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56330/discussion-between-crazy-developer-and-craig).